# Transfer Customer Data From Custom System to Magento2, possible?

Tags: magento2, php

I know there's a way to transfer data from **Magento1** to **Magento2** but I'm interested if there's a way to transfer data from **custom system** to **Magento2**?

Comment: you want to magento 1 customer data  to magento2 migration?

Comment: no from custom system, not magento1